# Difference of mouse wheel scrolling and touch pad scrolling (firefox)?

Tags: javascript, browser

I've created a parallax background effect in my webpage using the scroll event. I know I shouldn't do so due to asynchronous scrolling, it's just for the fun of it. Now, when I use my mouse wheel there is no jumping and jittering but when scrolling with the touch pad there is.
I've tried researching but as that is more or less a new "area" I lack the technical therms an know how to find something even remotely answering some of my questions, which are:

Is touch pad scrolling processed asynchronously (firefox) while mouse wheel is not? And is there a way to "look" into the "processing process"? On what "level" does this "processing" occur (in the browser?)? Is there any way to change something from that "process"? Or am I not even looking in the right direction to find the reason in the scrolling difference?

I looked at the website in Chrome, Edge, Opera (all no jittering (or almost none), both with smooth scrolling enabled and disabled) as well as on firefox on another device (jittering on touch pad). So it's probably browser related.

Direct answers or links to good explanations or even a hint to a word I can research would be nice, thanks.

Appendix (don't know if that's relevant): When scrolling with the touch-pad it only jitters while the fingers are on the pad, when the page is scrolling from the "remaining energy", there is no jittering.